# Can I use NS_SWIFT_NAME or NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT on a C enum to map a global function to a Swift property?

Tags: swift, objective-c, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have an enum like

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum) {
  MyEnumCase1,
  MyEnumCase2,
  ...
};
```

and a function that maps those enum values to arbitrary strings

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *myEnumString(MyEnum val);
```

Is it possible to expose this to Swift as a property?

I've tried

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *myEnumString(MyEnum val) NS_SWIFT_NAME(MyEnum.stringVal);
```

but the compiler gives me the warning "'swift_name' attribute argument must be a string literal specifying a Swift function name" and Swift callers don't see `stringVal` as a property on values of `MyEnum`.

and I've tried

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *myEnumString(MyEnum val) NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
```

but my Swift extension

```
extension MyEnum {
  var stringVal {
    return __myEnumString(self)
  }
}
```

can't find `__myEnumString()`.

Comment: I don't know how to solve your issue, but as a workaround I would define a new `@interface SomeName` and just crate a wrapper of `myEnumString` inside that interface. Another option is to convert code over to swift (since making enum and its extension visible from swift to objc is easier)

Comment: @Greg: Did you have a chance to check the answer? Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to revisit this yet. I'll post when I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Swift function name passed to `NS_SWIFT_NAME` must include the implicit `self:` argument, and to import it as a read-only property (instead of a method), "getter:" must be prepended. Various examples can be found in [SE-0044 Import as member](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md#swift_name-attribute).

So the correct syntax to expose the C function as a (read-only) property to Swift is

```
NSString *myEnumString(MyEnum val)
NS_SWIFT_NAME(getter:MyEnum.stringVal(self:));
```

The generated Swift interface is

```
extension MyEnum {
    public var stringVal: String { get }
}
```

and this compiles and runs as expected in my test:

```
print(MyEnum.case1.stringVal)
```